# Swingworker producing duplicate output/output out of order?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

What is the proper way to guarantee delivery when using a SwingWorker? I'm trying to route data from an InputStream to a JTextArea, and I'm running my SwingWorker with the `execute` method. I think I'm following the example [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), but I'm getting out of order results, duplicates, and general nonsense.

Here is my non-working SwingWorker:

```
class InputStreamOutputWorker extends SwingWorker<List<String>,String> {

    private InputStream is;
    private JTextArea output;

    public InputStreamOutputWorker(InputStream is, JTextArea output) {
        this.is = is;
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        byte[] data = new byte[4 * 1024];
        int len = 0;

        while ((len = is.read(data)) > 0) {
            String line = new String(data).trim();
            publish(line);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process( List<String> chunks )
    {
        for( String s : chunks )
        {
            output.append(s + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running more than one worker at a time?

Comment: Have you tried running it in the Swing Dispatcher Thread ?
Unless your input stream is reeeeaaaly slow (> 1 sec) then I would put it in the DispatchThread.  
There is not really enough code or context to identify any issues.

Comment: Only one worker is run at a time, and the input stream will take data for several hours.

Comment: What does `read()` return? Any exceptions? Is `is` modified elsewhere?

Comment: is is only read from and used within the swingworker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Clear your data array after reading from the input stream.

```
while ((len = is.read(data)) > 0) {
                String line = new String(data).trim();
                publish(line);
                Arrays.fill(data,(byte)0);
}
```

Comment: -1 - read the API or Fred's answer; you're creating a String with a lot of NUL characters in it

Comment: Not really, trim takes care of it. It may be slightly inefficient, but that's not where my bottleneck is at all in this application. is.read() takes about 1 second to respond, so anything I do in the loop is basically free. I'd -1 your comment for pre-optimization if I could.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'len' value when creating your string:

```
String line = new String(data,0,len).trim();
```

Also, I would recommend you wrap your InputStream in a BufferedReader and use the 'readLine()' method:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
...
String line = reader.readLine()
```